# Use PHP to find and replace html element content with a given classname within a document

Tags: php, json

I am working on a light-weight inline content editor for my site. Similar to [CushyCMS](http://cushycms.com/) or [SurrealCMS](http://surrealcms.com/), the 'editable' elements of my page are defined with a `class="editable"`.

I would like to pass 2 variables to php via AJAX:

`$page` The document to be written to (eg. '/path/index.html')

`$json` A json string: `{"0":"First Content","1":"Second Content","2":"Third Content"}` where the key is the index of all elements with `class="editable"` and the value is each element's innerHTML.

In PHP 5.3, how can I open `$page` and find/replace `class="editable"` elements?

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$json = $_POST['json'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($page);

// Detect DOM elements with class="editable"  & replace content with JSON data

// Save changes to designated file
$doc->saveHTMLFile($page); // Write to file eg, 'index.html'

echo ('Success');
```

Comment: What does your for loop output now?  Also, I wouldn't just "echo ('success')", I would do if(fwrite($fp, $html)) echo 'success';

Comment: Thanks for the echo tip! Right now I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'` on the line `foreach ($ret[$i]) {`.

Comment: Oh.  Yeah.  That's not foreach syntax.  I'll give an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath to track down all editable elements in the DOM.

```php
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('//*[@class="editable"]');
$edits = json_decode($json, true);
$num_edits = count($edits);

for($i=0; $i<$num_edits; $i++)
{
    $f = new DOMDocument();
    $edit = mb_convert_encoding($edits[$i], 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
    $f->loadHTML($edit);
    $node = $f->documentElement->firstChild;
    $entries->item($i)->nodeValue = "";
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $entries->item($i)->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
    }
}
```

Here it is again in the context of your original code:

```php
$page = $_POST['page'];
$json = $_POST['json'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($page);

// Detect DOM elements with class="editable"  & replace content with JSON data
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('//*[@class="editable"]');
$edits = json_decode($json, true);
$num_edits = count($edits);

for($i=0; $i<$num_edits; $i++)
{
    $f = new DOMDocument();
    $edit = mb_convert_encoding($edits[$i], 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
    $f->loadHTML($edit);
    $node = $f->documentElement->firstChild;
    $entries->item($i)->nodeValue = "";
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $entries->item($i)->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
    }
}

// Save changes to designated file
$doc->saveHTMLFile($page); // Write to file eg, 'index.html'

echo ('Success');
```

Comment: `nodeValue` seems to be converting my html tags to plain text. Is there anyway to keep it as innerHTML?

Comment: @Josiah: I improved the `for` loop due to the recent discovery that the old code only handled well-formed XHTML, but HTML. Now it should have no problems with either.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a job for [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [`simplehtmldom`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm new to PHP:). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a foreach loop for this if the for loop is providing the indices.  Try this:

```
// Write JSON content to class="editable" elements
for ($i = 0; $i < $ret->length; $i++) {
        echo $data[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/), a PHP library for manipulating XML and HTML. Like jQuery for PHP.

From their site:

> QueryPath is a PHP library for manipulating XML and HTML. It is
>   designed to work not only with local files, but also with web services
>   and database resources. It implements much of the jQuery interface,
>   but it is heavily tuned for server-side use.